# NodeJS as backend for Google polymer 1.0

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, firebase-hosting, polymer-starter-kit

i am developing site using polymer starter kit without any knowledge in Javascript & HTML,everything is fine with the UI .I've done the UI part of the site and i have also deployed the site in firebase referring their guidelines.I used firebase for storing the form data of my site.Now i want to use nodejs for importing data from firebase and perform some calculations and update firebase fields ,because several API such as Twilio are easy to use in nodejs.if i did so ,how can i host it as single website.i don't know what should i do !

Answer (score 1):

You have [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/quickstart.html) a simple code in node.js to retreive data from firebase.

After you install firebase library with npm, and set your app-token, 
you will be able to fetch data from firebase with this code:

```
    myFirebaseRef.child("location/city").on("value", function(snapshot) {
      alert(snapshot.val());  // Alerts "San Francisco"
    });
```

Comment: Twillio have a library for node.js [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/node/install)

Comment: You have their an example how to send an sms, you can put it in firebase code and change "alert" method

Comment: does tat mean it can be used with polymer !?

Comment: Polymer is for client side, node.js is for server side. You can fetch data from firebase and do it what you want from node.js. It's not depend how you enter data to firebase

Comment: alright i got it...i have done UI in polymer, if i use nodejs for doing those server side things how can i deploy them ?